# Entity Framework Core migrated from 2.2 to 3.1: Updating Foreign Key Object not working

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I migrated from .net Core 2.2 to 3.1 also with entity framework core.
Now I have something like this and I don't know why the update is not working (it worked in 2.2):

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ObjA : BaseEntity
{
    public int ObjBId {get; set; }
    public ObjB ObjB {get; set; }
}

public class ObjB : BaseEntity
{   

}

var listOfObjA = _dbContext.AObjects.Where(a => a.ObjBId == null);
if(listOfObjA.Any())
{
    ObjB objB = new ObjB();
    _dbContext.BObjects.Add(objB);
    foreach(var objA in listOfObjA)
    {
        objA.ObjB = objB;
        _dbContext.Entry(objA).CurrentValues.SetValues(objA);
    }
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

There is no error the code runs throught but the ObjB (and ObjBId) property is not updated it is null after the SaveChanges and the ObjB is created.

Comment: Can you share your `AObject` and  `ObjB`?

Comment: Also, can you post your error message?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
 objA.ObjB = objB;
 _dbContext.Entry(objA).CurrentValues.SetValues(objA);
```

try:

```
 context.Entry(objA).Property(u => u.ObjB).CurrentValue = objB;
context.Entry(objA).Property(u => u.ObjB).IsModified = true;
```